# Display different colors depending on percentage output

Tags: reporting-services, switch-statement, ssrs-2012

I have the following expression which I would like to display the result in a different color depending on the percentage output:

```
=IIF(isNothing(ReportItems!supply.value) or ReportItems!supply.value="" 
,nothing,
IIF(isNothing(ReportItems!cen.value) or ReportItems!cen.value="",nothing,
round((Cint(ReportItems!Textbox16.value)-Cint(ReportItems!Textbox17.value)) 
* 100 / Cint(ReportItems!Textbox16.Value),2) & "%"))</i>
```

How do I use this piece of code to display different colors? The Ranges are as follows:

- 0 - 50 is Green
- 50 - 70 is Black
- 70 - 100 is Red

If anyone can assist I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: Simple take your condition and wrap what colors you want based on true vs false.  For instance  `=IIF(Fields!NoAnswer.Value > 0, "Red", "Black")`

Answer (score 1):

Use a SWITCH statement for multiple conditions.  It is much easier to add to the conditions, and I think it is easier to read as well.

```
=SWITCH(Field.Value <= 50, "Green", Field.Value <=70,"Black",Field.Value <= 100,"Red",True,"Blue")
```

These are evaluated in order, using the first true result.  You should also always have a catch all value to prevent an error.  In this example, I've used `True` and set it to `Blue`.

Comment: To use this kind of logic with a complex expression like that in the OP, you would need to put it in a named textbox and refer to the relevant textbox with reportitems e.g. =Switch(ReportItems!namedtextbox.Value<=50%, "Green", etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly define colors dynamically, you just need to get the syntax right. The colors in SSRS can be defined by their hex value, for example white is `"#FFFFFF"`. Each pair of two hexadecimal positions corresponds to the Red, Green, and Blue portions of the color.

So if I wanted to use a number of 50 for the green portion of my color it would look like this:

```
="#00" + CStr(50) + "00"
```

In other words I am converting the number to a string and concatenating it with the rest of the color string in the required format. If you want to you can also use the `Hex` function to convert your integers into their corresponding hexadecimal value.